# Show On Screen Key Board on mouse left button down on PasswordBox and should Hide when click outside the box

Tags: c#, wpf

**Platform:** C# WPF

**Environment:** Visual Studio 2013

**Question # 1**: I want to show third party on screen keyboard on mouse left button down on `PasswordBox` control of C# WPF. I used the following code:

```
private void PasswordBox_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("D:\\CCOnScreenKeyboard.exe"); 
}
```

But it does not start on screen key board. Instead it triggers on `MouseDoubleClick` and `GotFocus` events.

**Question # 2**:

I want to Hide on screen keyboard when mouse click outside the `PasswordBox` and Show again on mouse left button down inside box.

**Question # 3**:

I want to show keyboard on single click instead of mouse double click

Comment: You might want to consider starting the process when your app starts and then only change the visibility of the OnscreenKeyboard form when needed. This might be less buggy.

Comment: Yes @ Maxter and also on mouse single click instead of double click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the parent window. Something like this:

```
bool isVisible = false;
PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (ss, ee) => 
{
    if (!passwordBox.IsMouseOver && isVisible)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("CCOnScreenKeyboard")?.FirstOrDefault()?.Kill();
    }
    else if (!isVisible)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("D:\\CCOnScreenKeyboard.exe");
        isVisible = true;

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive the best way to do this will be through using the `Focus` events, as you only want the keyboard when you're interacting with the `PasswordBox`, and for it to go once you have stopped interacting.

```
private void PasswordBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => 
    Process.Start("D:\\CCOnScreenKeyboard.exe");

private void PasswordBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("CCOnScreenKeyboard"))
        process.Kill();
}
```